# rewriting "trying to get out" with verb DO

Tags: idioms

In rewriting the sentence "where there was a stampede of people trying to get out" I am asked to write a sentence with simimilar meaning using the verb DO in this precise form. Any suggestions?

Comment: ... doing their best to get out.

Comment: Something colloquial or even slang? "...trying to do a runner." "... trying to do an exit-stage-left."  "... trying to do like a tree and leave." (Ouch!)  Something with a pop culture reference? "... trying to do like The Animals and Get Outta This Place."

Comment: thanks puppetsock, after having a look at the meanings of the expressions that you suggested I think the most appropriate one for the context would be "to do a runner".